# How to save textbox data to file using FolderBrowsedialog

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog

Am new to VB.NET. In the Below code when i compile it, Am getting an error when i check the **Select** Radiobutton and browse the folder and clikc the **GENERATE HL7 Message** am getting an error as "**Error: Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.**"  when i check the **Default** Radiobutton it works like a charm. But when i check the **Select** Radiobutton am getting the error. I don't know whats wrong in my code. you can find my design in the following URL: [URL=http://s1065.photobucket.com/user/Izaz_Ahmed/media/Capture_zpst4jjgvxb.jpg.html]

```
Private Sub HL_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HL.Click

        If vld(TxtProcode) = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        Dim folderBrowser As New FolderBrowserDialog
        Dim fileDateTime As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss") & ".HL7"
        Dim ts As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss")
        'file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\pdata\New folder\" & fileDateTime, True)
        folderBrowser.ShowNewFolderButton = True
        If RadioBtndefault.Checked Then
            TxtDob.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
            TxtDob.CustomFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
            TxtExamtime.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
            TxtExamtime.CustomFormat = "hhMMss"
            TxtExamdate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
            TxtExamdate.CustomFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
            file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\pdata\New folder\" & fileDateTime, True)
            file.WriteLine("MSH|^~\&|||||" & TxtExamdate.Text & "" & TxtExamtime.Text & "||ORM^O01||P|2.3.1")
            file.WriteLine("PID|||" & TxtId.Text & "||" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "^" & TxtGivenname.Text & "||" & TxtDob.Text & "||" & TxtGender.Text & "|||" & TxtStreet.Text & " " & TxtHouse.Text & "^^" & TxtCity.Text & "^^" & TxtPostcode.Text)
            file.WriteLine("PV1||O|||||||||||||||||" & TxtId.Text & "|||||||||||||||||||||||||" & ts)
            file.WriteLine("ORC|NW|" & ts & "|||||^^^S||" & TxtExamdate.Text)
            file.WriteLine("OBR||" & ts & "^" & ts & "||" & TxtProcode.Text & "|||" & TxtExamdate.Text & "" & TxtExamtime.Text & "|" & TxtExamdate.Text & "" & TxtExamtime.Text)
            file.WriteLine()
            file.Close()
        End If

        If RadioBtnselect.Checked Then
            If folderBrowser.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                file.WriteLine = folderBrowser.SelectedPath
                file.WriteLine("MSH|^~\&|||||" & TxtExamdate.Text & "" & TxtExamtime.Text & "||ORM^O01||P|2.3.1")
                file.WriteLine("PID|||" & TxtId.Text & "||" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "^" & TxtGivenname.Text & "||" & TxtDob.Text & "||" & TxtGender.Text & "|||" & TxtStreet.Text & " " & TxtHouse.Text & "^^" & TxtCity.Text & "^^" & TxtPostcode.Text)
                file.WriteLine("PV1||O|||||||||||||||||" & TxtId.Text & "|||||||||||||||||||||||||" & ts)
                file.WriteLine("ORC|NW|" & ts & "|||||^^^S||" & TxtExamdate.Text)
                file.WriteLine("OBR||" & ts & "^" & ts & "||" & TxtProcode.Text & "|||" & TxtExamdate.Text & "" & TxtExamtime.Text & "|" & TxtExamdate.Text & "" & TxtExamtime.Text)
                file.WriteLine()
                file.Close()
                Dim root As Environment.SpecialFolder = folderBrowser.RootFolder
            End If
        End If
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact error message is caused by this line

```
 file.WriteLine = folderBrowser.SelectedPath
```

`WriteLine` is a method not a property. The syntax shoud be WriteLine(....).

In any case your code will fail because the StreamWriter used in the Select case is not initalized correctly as you do in the first case.
You need something like this that combine the SelectedPath with your intended file name

```
If RadioBtnselect.Checked Then
    If folderBrowser.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim destFile = Path.Combine(folderBrowser.SelectedPath,fileDateTime)
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(destFile,True)      
        file.WriteLine(.....)
        .....
```

Comment: When implement this a getting an error as "**Error:Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'OpenTextFileWriter' accepts this number of arguments.**"

Comment: Right forget the second parameter it could be a boolean True to append the text to an existing file or a boolean False to overwrite an existing file with the new data. According to your first block I have used True to append

Answer (score 0):

Look at your second condition, RadioBtnselect statement. You never tell the `StreamWriter` the path, hence your error. You do give it a path in your first if but not in the second one.

For example this:

```
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\pdata\New folder\" & fileDateTime, True)
```